# Upsert parent and child in single DML using there own ExternalIDs

Tags: apex

I have a requirement to upsert parent records by External ID ExtParent__c field. And upsert child records by its External ID ExtChild__c field.

```
For this, I used:

upsert parentRecord ExtParent__c; //which inserts parent records

upsert childrecord ExtChild__c; // which inserts child records
```

Now, Is there a way to insert both these related records using single DML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming parent and child are the same sObject type (this is required for upsert), you can link the records as such:

```
mySObjectType[] records = new mySObjectType[] {
  new mySObjectType(Name='Parent',ExternalId__c='123'),
  new mySObjectType(Name='Child',ExternalId__c='456',Parent__r=new mySObjectType(ExternalId__c='123'))
};
upsert records mySobjectType.ExternalId__c;
```

If you're inserting or updating, you can use the same technique, even for different sObjects. However, there is a limitation on upsert that prevents you from mixing sObject types in the same list.

So, if the parent and child are the same type (e.g. Account), you can use upsert this way, but if the parent and child are of a different type, then you cannot specifically use upsert in a single DML statement. You would need two DML statements, or use either insert or update (e.g. creating the parent and child at once would be acceptable). The parent must be created earlier in the list than the child.

Comment: Okay,as parent and child are 2 different sObjects related to each other. So, what would be mySobjectType value? Should I take mySObjectType[] as list of sObject[]?

Comment: @sfdc07 You can't use generic `List<sobject>` for upsert. If you know you're inserting or updating both, you can use this design. Otherwise, you do unfortunately need two DML statements.

Comment: Okay, so, what exactly would come in place of  'mySObjectType'?

Comment: @sfdc07 Again, this design won't work if they are two different sObject types. You will need to use insert or update, or use two separate DML statements, as in your original question.

Comment: Without the clarifications from these comments I personally feel the answer needs more detail in order to be upvoted (strictly it does not answer the question, which shows using two different external ID fields, but rather infers the answer "no").

Comment: @PhilW I stated twice that the sObject for parent and child must be the same for upsert (and only upsert). That said, I did roll up the extra info from the comments into the answer as well.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I would still say explicitly, at the beginning of the answer, that you can only use the one external ID field across all records upserted together (which you do show but don't state)...

Answer (score 0):

I've dived into the [documents](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_limitations.htm) and found that on a single DML we can't include self-referenced objects.
On the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) we can see that inserting different type of parent and child records is possible.
I can't see a way that how upserting is possible on ***sfdcfox***'s example.

> You can’t add a record that references another record of the same
> object type in the same call. For example, the Contact object has a
> Reports To field that’s a reference to another contact. You can’t
> create two contacts in one call if one contact uses the Reports To
> field to reference a second contact in the input array. You can create
> a contact that references another contact that has been previously
> created.
>
> Records for multiple object types are broken into multiple chunks by
> Salesforce. A chunk is a subset of the input array, and each chunk
> contains records of one object type. Data is committed on a
> chunk-by-chunk basis. Any Apex triggers that are related to the
> records in a chunk are invoked once per chunk.